# Material-UI Divider adds a scrollbar on the right hand side of the screen, when I remove it from the component, no ScrollBar

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Is there any way to remove the scrollbar, it is being added whenever I add the divider to my Home, right below the menu.

Here is the code

```
    return (
      <Box className={classes.root}>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <Header />
        </Grid>
        <Divider flexItem={true} className={classes.headerDivider}/>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          {body}
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <Footer/>
        </Grid>
      </Box>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: horizontal scroll?

Comment: Yes it is a horizontal scroll that adds by itself because of the divider.

Answer (score 0):

Add css to hide horizontal scroll

```
.some-box-class {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```